# Roadblock installing 4-way switch

Tags: electrical, switch

I've been trying to install a four way switch setup for a ceiling fan using a Leviton z-wave control switch and two matching remotes.

I've attached a copy of the wiring as it is currently set up. I'm replacing old switch so have had to do a bit of guesswork as to what line is what.

The thing that has been throwing me off is this extra switch, that I initially thought had nothing to do with the light at all. When I pulled everything out of the gang box though it was spliced in with the switch neutral wire.

It seems like this is an extra switch before the load, and then the other three are after the load. I don't know why it's there though, since two of the switches are in the same gang box.

Any guidance on how to wire this correctly is very welcome!
[image]

Comment: That question mark worries me. All switches should be on the hot side of the load unless they're just transmitters and have no load.

Comment: So I've learned that the previous electrician wired the neutral from the 3-wire circuit to the hot from the mystery switch, thereby supplying current when the switch is open. Why would he do this? Does this suggest that the control switch is actually in front of the load?